# Using \vfill* prints the asterisk

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column, starred-version

I'm using \vfill* to unbalance columns in a twocolumn environment.  The columns are filled with a series of figure environments that I'm using to keep blocks of text together.  I would like the figures to be at the top of the page, with the whitespace at the bottom, rather than spaced out, which seems to be the default when using twocolumn.  `\vfill*` works great, except that it prints the asterisk at the bottom of the page.  I found examples of people using `\vspace*{\fill}`, but this doesn't work for the document I'm working with.  Using `\vfill \break` was also suggested, but it only works for the right column.  Using `\vfill \columnbreak` shifts my content off the page.  I'm using xelatex to compile, since I'm using mathspec.  Does anyone know why the asterisk is printing, and how to prevent this?  Or, does anyone know a better way to unbalance the columns?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer consectetur tincidunt vestibulum. Sed sed enim id ante posuere sodales. Mauris porttitor sollicitudin neque et sollicitudin. 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
Mauris lacinia suscipit odio eget bibendum. Curabitur facilisis, felis sit amet venenatis tempus, massa lectus dignissim dui, ut vehicula nibh sem ac massa. 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
Morbi et tortor id leo rhoncus facilisis nec id quam. Phasellus porttitor, augue et viverra tempor, nisi leo fringilla erat, a iaculis eros felis id magna.
\end{figure} 
\vfill*
\begin{figure}[H]
Nam vitae lorem nunc. Sed viverra, dui nec egestas auctor, ligula arcu fringilla velit, at volutpat justo odio vitae turpis. Curabitur eget nibh justo.
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer consectetur tincidunt vestibulum. Sed sed enim id ante posuere sodales. Mauris porttitor sollicitudin neque et sollicitudin. 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\mbox{}\vfill`?

Comment: `\vfill` is a TeX primitive and has no starred version or other arguments

Comment: Using mbox didn't give me exactly the spacing I was looking for.  It got rid of some of the whitespace, but not all of it, as vfill was doing.

Comment: @cgnieder I didn't realize that, I guess I assumed since hspace had a starred version, vspace did as well.  Simply using \vfill doesn't produce the same result, however.  Why would that be?

Comment: @user27446 `\vspace` does have a star form but you didn't use it.

Comment: `\vspace` has indeed a *-version; but `\vfill` isn't `\vspace`, is it? Neither `\hfill` has a *-variant.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that confusion for me.  I was unaware of that about vfill and hfill.  I think that what was happening was that vfill wasn't spacing the figures as much as I wanted, because it still had room in the column.  When I was putting text after it, however, it assumed I wanted the rest of the content pushed away from that text.  Using \vfill \mbox{} is producing the results I want.

Comment: if you want all the space at the bottom, maybe `\raggedbottom` is what you want for those pages. (reset with `\flushbottom`.)

Answer (score 2):

do not use float environments, use minipages instead and if you need captions then use package `caption` and `\captionof{figure}{...}`. This allows to use `\newpage`. `\vfill` is then not needed:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer consectetur tincidunt vestibulum. Sed sed enim id ante posuere sodales. Mauris porttitor sollicitudin neque et sollicitudin. 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Mauris lacinia suscipit odio eget bibendum. Curabitur facilisis, felis sit amet venenatis tempus, massa lectus dignissim dui, ut vehicula nibh sem ac massa. 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Morbi et tortor id leo rhoncus facilisis nec id quam. Phasellus porttitor, augue et viverra tempor, nisi leo fringilla erat, a iaculis eros felis id magna.
\end{minipage} 

%\vfill
\newpage
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Nam vitae lorem nunc. Sed viverra, dui nec egestas auctor, ligula arcu fringilla velit, at volutpat justo odio vitae turpis. Curabitur eget nibh justo.
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer consectetur tincidunt vestibulum. Sed sed enim id ante posuere sodales. Mauris porttitor sollicitudin neque et sollicitudin. 
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```